# wp meta_query meta_value compare =REGEXP delimited by space

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

searching for custom_tel inside custom post type for meta value

> example 
>   in database it is save like this 75213332 bla bla bla bla ..

what i have done sent 75213332 and did REGEXP but that did not work good it return custom_tel that not equal to 75213332

> part of WP_Query()

```
  array(
  'key' => 'custom_tel',
  'value' =>'^'.$tel.'@',
  'compare' => 'REGEXP'
  );
```

please help ?

Answer (score 0):

### solution for this question is :

taking the example above  75213332 bla bla bla bla ..
to search for all post that have the custom_tel 75213332 the REGEXP will be ^(75213332) so in this case

```
array(
  'key' => 'custom_tel',
  'value' =>'^('.$tel.')',
  'compare' => 'REGEXP'
  )
```